# Why does the node global context === 'this' only sometimes, in a sample?

Tags: node.js, this

I have the following test.js file that emits two lines of output, each line tests for strict equality between the global object and `this`.

```
var c = require("console");

console.log(this === global);

(function () {
    console.log(this === global);
})();
```

When I run this file from the command line using `node.exe test.js` I get the following output:

> false
>   true

However when I load test.js from inside the node REPL it provides me different output:

> true
>   true

This is the full transcript of loading the script in the REPL

```
PS C:\Programming> node
> .load test.js
.load test.js
> var c = require("console");
undefined
> console.log(this === global);
true
undefined
>
> (function () {
...     console.log(this === global);
... })();
true
undefined
>
> .exit
```

**What is the cause of difference in output between these two run scenarios of the same script?**

Strict mode is not enabled in either case (node command line sets strict to false by default); the code doesn't invoke strict mode with `'use strict';`.

I'm using node 5.9.0 on Windows 10 x64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the two environments are different. When you execute a file on the command line or `require()` a file, they are loaded as node modules which are executed in a special environment where `this === module.exports` (although you should use `exports`/`module.exports` instead of `this` in modules).

There is no sense in treating a REPL like a node module due to the nature/purpose of a REPL, so all of the code in the REPL is simply executed within the same scope.